# Good websites to test webcrawler on

Tags: web-crawler

I'm testing out a new webcrawler and I'm looking for some good websites that might trip it up (redirects, frames, anything).  Does anybody know of some really complicated sites, or ones that might trip it up?  Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you test it on the Alexa top 1000 or so, you'll get a pretty representative sample of what goes on in websites. You may not get a chance to test some legacy protocols (e.g. frameset, so on and so forth), but you'll get a pretty good idea of performance especially where it counts.